# How many quotients can a finitely generated group have or how many bundles over aspherical spaces does a fixed total space support?

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, dg.differential-geometry, gr.group-theory

Consider $M^3_{pq}$,
a torus bundle over $S^1$ with fundamental group the HNN extension generated by three generators $x,y,z$ satisfying the relations $\quad [x,y], \quad x^z = x^p \quad$ and $y^z = y^q$.
By the exact homotopy sequence, $M^3_{pq}$ is aspherical.

Suppose there is a closed manifold $E^{n+3}$ that is the total space of a $T^n$ bundle over infinitely many $M^3_{pq}$ satisfying $p\neq q$. As $M_{pq}^3$ is aspherical, so is $E$.
Hence,
this can only be the case if $\pi_1 M_{pq}$ is a quotient of $\pi_1 E$ by the fundamental group $\pi_1T^n$; note that $\pi_1E$ and $n$ may not depend on $(p,q)$.
It seems unlikely that one can obtain an infinite amount of mutually non-isomorphic, non-abelian groups as quotients from a finitely generated group by only identifying elements that commute. However, I have failed to prove this.

This begs the general question: How many exact sequences with non-abelian groups $H$
$$
0 \rightarrow Z^n \rightarrow G \rightarrow H \rightarrow e
$$
can a finitely presented group $G$ admit for fixed $n$? What are possible obstructions, aside from the kernel of $G\rightarrow H$ having to be abelian?

Comment: You have a very specific requirements on the kernel which are not in your title.  This is a very different question - of course, a free group has a huge number of quotients; I suggest editing your title.

Comment: Also, if I'm not mistaken, in your example $E^{n+3}$ is aspherical. This should be important.  My guess is that there *are* finitely generated $G$'s with infinitely many distinct quotients by fg free abelian subgroups - indeed, as a general rule (in fact I think it's a meta-theorem of Gromov), when someone says 'it seems unlikely that there is a finitely generated group with property P', they are almost invariably wrong.  But it may well be that there are no examples of 'type F' (ie fundamental groups of compact aspherical complexes).

Comment: Thank you, Henry. I implicitly used that $E$ is aspherical to obtain the short exact sequence in the third paragraph, but I have pointed it out more clearly now.

Comment: @Malte: Your description of fundamental groups of 3-manifolds fibering over circle with torus fiber is way too limited, it works only for $|p|=|q|=1$. The right thing to do is to take some matrix $A$ in $GL(2,Z)$ and use it to define semidirect product of $Z^2$ and $Z$. 

Comment: Hmm... could you elaborate on that, Misha? 
Just to clarify: I am considering surface bundles that are obtained by taking the mapping torus of some diffeomorphism of the surface. In this case, the surface is a torus and the diffeomorphism is the composition of two Dehn twists.

In general, I would get an element of $GL(2,Z)$. But where is the problem with having $p,q > 1$?

Comment: @Malte: Your presentation gives a diagonal matrix with diagonal entries $p, q$. Such matrix is in $GL(2,Z)$ iff $|p|=|q|=1$. You should write presentation in the form $x^z=x^a y^c, y^z=x^b y^d$, where $a,b,c,d$ are entries in a matrix from $GL(2,Z)$. 

Answer (score 6):

Take a finitely presented non-Abelian perfect group $H$  (i.e. $H=[H,H]$). Take $G=H\times \mathbb{Z}$. Then you have infinitely (countably) many short exact sequences

$$1\to \mathbb{Z}\to G\to H\times \mathbb{Z}/m\mathbb{Z}\to 1.$$

On the other hand, for every finitely generated group $G$ there are at most countably many short exact sequences of the form

$$ 1\to \mathbb{Z}^n\to G\to H\to 1.$$

Comment: I interpreted the question as asking for non-isomorphic quotients.

Comment: $H\times \mathbb{Z}/m\mathbb{Z}$ are all non-isomorphic because $H$ has trivial abelianization. 


Comment: Oh right, yes, apologies.  I was fixing $m$ for some reason.  That's quite trivial!

Comment: Perhaps it's more interesting if you also require the quotient to be of type F?

Comment: One can get a central extension of $H$ with center $C=\mathbb{Z^2}$. Then choose maximal cyclic subgroups $N$ in $C$. The groups $H/N$ are most probably pairwise non-isomorphic (one needs to prove it!) and will be of type $F$ for a suitable $H$. 

Comment: Ah yes, that should work. You can probably take some central extension of a surface group and produce countably many cyclic central extension quotients with distinct Euler classes.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, Mark. However, I believe that the question becomes harder if one requires that $H$ be centre-free (as is the case for $H = \pi_1 M_{pq}$, or similar families of surface bundles with fixed fibre genus).

Comment: @Malte: If you specify all the properties of the group you need, it would be easier to answer. Now it is like a "moving target". It is not really necessary to have a center, just a big enough list of Abelian normal subgroups. For example, one can modify examples I gave and make centerless groups. Of course if your assumptions become more and more restrictive, eventually the answer will be "no" (at an intermediate step, the answer may also be "unknown").

Comment: I apologise for being inconvenient. My interest in this question really comes from the example given in the question (this is why I added "centre-free" to the list of properties).

Comment: @Malte: Could you formulate the question precisely? Are you considering only abelian-by-cyclic groups? There are (relatively old) papers about groups with max-n condition (ascending chain condition for normal subgroups), i.e. groups where every infinite increasing chain of normal subgroups stabilizes, and  solvable groups with similar condition on Abelian normal subgroups.   

Comment: http://plms.oxfordjournals.org/content/s3-4/1/419.extract